# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found?

Tags: java, web-applications, server, catalina, tomcat8

Any body ever had this error before: I made some minor changes to ensure that the connections in my DB connection pool was being released, ran it and tried to login and this error was thrown. I am assuming that this is something on the server side seeing as how the first line is a direct reference to Catalina but I am not really sure where to start looking.

```
Oct 29, 2014 9:40:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider     org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlBaseTLV.validate(JstlBaseTLV.java:161)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV.validate(JstlCoreTLV.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.validate(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateXmlView(Validator.java:1883)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1852)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at com.secureautodata.control.LoginControl.handler(LoginControl.java:199)
    at com.secureautodata.control.LoginControl.doPost(LoginControl.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222     )
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you tell me the what are the changes you are done for connectin pool

Comment: @pie The only changes I made were literally just closing statements, there is nothing in the changes that I made that would point to this error that I can find. I forgot a couple of closing statements and free connection statements so I added them in and tried to run it, and this happened.

Comment: It look's like there is problem in the jsp

Comment: @pie The problem with that is I didn't change anything in the JSP's and it was working on a different computer at my office...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that my pom.xml file presented a dependency that was in conflict with a couple of .jar files that I had added to my library. The main one was the mysql connector jar, I had reinstalled tomcat on my computer at work and as a quick work around instead of including the jar in my tomcat library I just added it to my pom.xml as a dependency causing a conflict with my tomcat and IDE setup on my home computer.

After removing this dependency from the pom.xml and my jstl dependency from my pom.xml everything worked like a dream. Being as my program had the .jar files included they were just bumping heads.